# APACHE PHOENIX ERROR: org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool - ERROR IN CONSTRAINT

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I Execute the next command in CLI:

```
hbase org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool -Dhbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily=1024 -t TABLE -c ID,c1,c2,c3 -i /hive_to_hbase/output_2023.csv
```

And that execution returning the next:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 218 (23018): Constraint violation. TABLE.ID may not be null
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.FormatToBytesWritableMapper.map(FormatToBytesWritableMapper.java:212)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.FormatToBytesWritableMapper.map(FormatToBytesWritableMapper.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:799)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 218 (23018): Constraint violation. TEST_DM_CDR_DWH.ID may not be null
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.FormatToBytesWritableMapper$MapperUpsertListener.errorOnRecord(FormatToBytesWritableMapper.java:409)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.csv.CsvUpsertExecutor.execute(CsvUpsertExecutor.java:100)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.csv.CsvUpsertExecutor.execute(CsvUpsertExecutor.java:52)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.UpsertExecutor.execute(UpsertExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.FormatToBytesWritableMapper.map(FormatToBytesWritableMapper.java:181)
```

I created the tables with the next sql sentences in apache-phoenix:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DM_CDR_DWH(
    id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    "COLUMNS"."c1" VARCHAR,
    "COLUMNS"."c2" VARCHAR,
    "COLUMNS"."c3" VARCHAR
)TTL=31536000,COMPRESSION='ZSTD';
```

and with this index

```
CREATE INDEX TEST_DM_CDR_DWH_IDX ON TEST_DM_CDR_DWH ("COLUMNS"."c1") INCLUDE("COLUMNS"."c2");
```

Somebody can it explain to me, please?

I only search answer on google.